# HTML5Forms (support input type="range" in IE7+)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, cross-browser

I am trying to use the HTML5Forms library to use the input type="range" in IE7+. I have linked the scripts and am now wondering what am I missing. This is what I have so far and yes - the resources ARE correctly linked. I have tried using webshims-lib too with no result. [Here](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/) is a link to the library's explanations and [that's](https://github.com/zoltan-dulac/html5Forms.js) the download link to github.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html5Forms/shared/js/modernizr.com/Modernizr-2.5.3.forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html5Forms/shared/js/html5Forms.js"></script>
```

Comment: "HTML5" and "IE7" are not objects which could be fit together with each other...

Comment: Ah the joys of supporting old IE. HTML 5 and IE6 / 7 just don't play nicely

Comment: I quite understood that, after a bunch of long hours... xD But my task remains the same, I just need to find a polyfill